# Getting Nullpointer Exception

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng

While i run this below code i am getting Null pointer exception.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class GoogleTestTestng {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
    @Test
    public void googleTitleTest() {
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title);
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What was the exception? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GoogleTestTestng {
WebDriver driver;  //  This is your first problem.

@BeforeMethod
public void setup(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  //  This is your second problem.
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://google.com");
}
@Test
public void googleTitleTest() {
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);
}
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

Now, an explanation of what happened here.

```
WebDriver driver;  //  This is your first problem.
```

What you did here is *perfectly* fine to do.  In fact, I use this approach with my own automated tests.  Your code is ready to initialize a `WebDriver` object.

Now, here is where you ran into an issue:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  //  This is your second problem.
```

Which driver instance do you want to use here?  You initialize one at the top of your code then declare it a *second time here*?  As Rao, had mentioned, the fix for your problem is the following:

```
WebDriver driver;
<...More code here...>
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

What you have done here is removed the ambiguity between both `driver objects` you had created by declaring it once, *and then* instantiating it once you are ready to use it.

Oh, and as a side note, I noticed that your `implicit wait` is for a very long time.  Be careful with how long you set your timeouts for if execution speed is something you are striving for in your tests.

Answer (score 3):

you're trying to call method of an object that does not exist.

Try this out

```
 driver= new ChromeDriver();
```

change in your code

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class GoogleTestTestng {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver(); //this portion i have changed
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
    @Test
    public void googleTitleTest() {
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title);
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```